# How to print stack-trace programmatically?

Tags: debugging, apportable

I am writing some error handling code, and I want to print stack trance for any C/C++ exceptions. How can I print stack-trace programmatically?

Comment: Well... I could put a symbolic breakpoint on `__cxa_throw`.

Comment: If apportable implements it, output `[NSThread callStackSymbols]`. I have no idea whether it does, hence this being a comment.